# Validation of the jwt received from keycloak

Tags: c++, validation, jwt, keycloak

There is a separate system in which authorization is done via Keycloak. After authorization, I get the corresponding jwt token, which has the name of the authorized user.
Also, I have a separate C++ service that is not part of this system. I would like to authorize the user in this service based on the token received.
Do I understand correctly that the only possible option to make sure that the token was generated from this separate system is to make a request for validation to keycloak?
If so, please tell me the correct way to validate the remote token in keycloak.

I was looking for similar solutions, but mostly I found options where authorization also takes place in this service, and not separately in the source system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak is usually configured to follow the OpenID Connect standard. If so, the JWT can be validated by verifying its signature using Keycloak's public key.

If your Keycloak server is publicly available, you can easily test it by pasting the JWT on the website [jwt.io](https://jwt.io). If it displays "Signature Verified" at the bottom, the JWT is fully self-contained.

To validate it in C++:

- Decode it into header, payload and signature as shown on *jwt.io*
- Take the URL from the `iss` attribute, e.g. `https://keycloak.abc.com/auth/realms/ab1`
- Extend the URL with `/.well-known/openid-configuration` so it becomes `https://keycloak.abc.com/auth/realms/ab1/.well-known/openid-configuration` and retrieve the JSON document from that URL
- From the JSON, take the URL of the `jwks_uri` attribute, e.g. `https://keycloak.abc.com/auth/realms/ab1/protocol/openid-connect/certs` and retrieve it. It's a JSON file again and contains one or multiple public keys.
- Take the public key with the same `kid` as the `kid` value in the JWT header and validate the signature according to the specified algorithm.

Note:

- Always validate that `iss` attribute is the URL of the Keycloak server you trust. After all, you don't want to accept JWTs of any OIDC server.
- It makes sense to cache the Keycloak public keys. You can retrieve the public keys independently from validating JWTs so that the validation does not require any network requests.
- You'll want to use a library for this as implementing the whole suite of cryptographic algorithms isn't easy. Use https://jwt.io/libraries as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Does this approach guarantee that the token cannot be fake?

Comment: Absolutely. This is a well-established approach based on signatures using public/private keys.